# Rails: Temporarily storing video on Heroku in order to upload to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a scheduler task which downloads a video from a url. I want to temporarily store this on my Heroku server just long enough so that I can upload it to S3. I can't figure out a way to upload directly from external URL to S3, so instead I'm using my server as the 'middle man'.

But I don't understand where I should be storing the file on my server, or if Heroku will even allow it.

Comment: Do you know which [stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack) you're on? Cedar, Cedar-14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on the Cedar or Cedar-14 [stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack), you can write the file anywhere on the filesystem.

You're probably aware (if not, you should be) that Heroku Dynos have an ephemeral filesystem and that this filesystem is discarded the moment a dyno is stopped or restarted - which can happen for any number of reasons. With that in mind, you'll probably want to design your task scheduler in such a way that failed jobs are retried a couple of times.

Comment: So right now I'm just saving the files to root.. No need to worry because they'll be wiped frequently?

Comment: Yeah, at minimum Dynos are restarted [approximately once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) so you should be fine.